# Restricted ports to non-admins on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, security, port, sockets

I work in a restrictive desktop/network environment and I am not an admin on my laptop.  The ports available to me are limited.  E.g. when I tried running Tomcat, the system refused to open a socket on the port for which Tomcat was asking.

However, some port ranges are obviously open as I can, for example, use the internet, network, and connect to Unix boxes using SSH.  When I was on the Unix box, I used `netstat` to find out from which ports my IP made multiple connections.  Then I tried to write a Java program to open a port in that ballpark (51K range) and it succeeded.  On another random port (e.g. in the 4000 range) I could not mount a socket.

So my question is this: how can I get a listing of the security policy on my laptop, even if it is read-only, so I can see which ports are available to me and which are not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should help:

http://www.portdetective.com

http://www.auditmypc.com/firewall-test.asp

Comment: isn't there a flat file on the system where i can get this listing?  i can get in trouble trying to use those web apps.

Comment: The blocks are most likely at the network level, as configured by the admin. If these apps might get you into trouble and you have a legit reason for wanting this info., why not just ask your n/w admin to give you a list?